# Reorder rows in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Name              |  Order    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | John              | 1         |
| 2      | Mike              | 3         |
| 3      | Daniel            | 4         |
| 4      | Lisa              | 2         |
| 5      | Joe               | 5         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

The order can be changed by admin hence the order column. On the admin side I have a form with a select box `Insert After:` to entries to the database. What query should I use to order+1 after the inserted column.

I want to do this in a such way that keeps server load to a minimum because this table has 1200 rows at present. Is this the correct way to save an order of the table or is there a better way?

Any help appreciated

**EDIT:**

Here's what I want to do, thanks to itsmatt:

want to reorder row number 1 to be after row 1100, you plan to leave 2-1100 the same and then modify 1 to be 1101 and increment 1101-1200

Comment: So, if you want to reorder row number 1 to be after row 1100, you plan to leave 2-1100 the same and then modify 1 to be 1101 and increment 1101-1200?  Just trying to get an idea of what you want here.

Comment: Is it wise to change the order number? I would have thought this may lead to confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
   SET `Order` = `Order` + 1 
 WHERE `Order` > (SELECT `Order` 
                    FROM MyTable 
                   WHERE ID = <insert-after-id>);
```

...which will shift the order number of every row further down the list than the person you're inserting after.

Then:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, `Order`)
VALUES (Name, (SELECT `Order` + 1 FROM MyTable WHERE ID = <insert-after-id>));
```

To insert the new row (assuming ID is auto increment), with an order number of one more than the person you're inserting after.

Comment: getting this error `You can't specify target table 'test_cat' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @LeePrice, you need to surround the subselect in another subselect like so: `... where order > (select * from (select order from mytable where id = ...))` _(The ways of MySQL are strange)_

Comment: now i'm getting this: `Every derived table must have its own alias` :/

Answer (score 1):

Just add the new row in any normal way and let a later SELECT use ORDER BY to sort. 1200 rows is infinitesimally small by MySQL standards. You really don't have to (and don't want to) keep the physical table sorted. Instead, use keys and indexes to access the table in a way that will give you what you want.

Answer (score -2):

you can

```
insert into tablename (name, `order`) 
values( 'name', select `order`+1 from tablename where name='name')
```

you can also you id=id_val in your inner select.

Hopefully this is what you're after, the question isn't altogether clear.

Comment: this won't work as given because `order` is a reserved keyword in SQL. You need to wrap it in backticks to make MySQL see it as a fieldname and not a keyword.

Comment: what about using `max(order)+1`

Comment: @diEcho: That would work on a single connection system, but you will run into concurrency issues when running this query in parallel.

Comment: -1 This query will not work, A: the select will select multiple rows, throwing you insert statement off B: `limit 1` will not help because that will just select a indeterminate row C: `order by 'order' DESC limit 1` will work **most** of the time but will run into concurrency issues if you run the query in parallel.