# Reorder rows in DB table when deleting an element

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a good answer to Reordering rows in a DB table when inserting an element:
[Reorder rows in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649180/reorder-rows-in-a-mysql-table)
But what about when deleting a row? What would the queries be in this case?

Comment: When you insert a new one, you add plus one to the order. Using common sense, what do you need to do, when you delete a record?

Answer (score 0):

> Reordering rows in a DB table when inserting an element

That's strange cause per my knowledge there is no inherent order maintained in your DB table. would have that been the case then there won't be any need of `order by` clause.

In a single sentence, no specific order gets maintained in your table and so while fetching record from table you will have order the data using `order by` clause per your need.

Not sure what you mean by *re-ordering* the table data.

Comment: Check the topic linked in the question, there is a separate order field in the table.

Comment: Btw,  innodb tables are clustered around pk, so the records are stored in a particular order.

Comment: @Shadow, Ahh!! ok ... but not sure whether OP also has a manual ordering and so this stands a generic answer. Will delete once OP clarifies

Comment: @Shadow, NO, I don't think so and really doubt on that. Put a question saying the same and see what other says. There is no physical orders per my know.

Comment: No need for question, read mysql documentation on clustered indexes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: Folks, please do not vote down the question that you did not understand. I am specifically not interested in a read query that will return something using "order by". I am specifically interested in keeping the records themselves ordered physically in a small table using a designated column: priority. The link I've provided in the question discusses specifically that, but only offers the solution when a new element is inserted. My question is the same as at the link, but about deleting an element

Comment: Thanks Shadow, you're correct: "Check the topic linked in the question, there is a separate order field in the table". Indeed, there is a column (that keeps the physical order) in the table. Since the table is relatively small, it is possible to re-order the whole table physically and keep that priority order field up to date after each insert or delete which, in turn, are not that frequent. The reason I need the order in exact sequence (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on) is because joins with other tables need to know the exact order/priority number assigned to a particular row. That's the point

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this yet, it's quite late in the day, will test it some other time, but this might do the trick:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET `Order` = `Order` - 1 
WHERE `Order` > (SELECT `Order` 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID = <delete-row-id>);
```