# MySQL: Order rows in table after insertion

Tags: mysql

I have deleted some rows from a table in MySQL, then added some other rows in their place. Now when I do `SELECT ... FROM ...` the data is not sorted. I know, that when selecting data I can use `order by id ASC`, but that only prints the ordered rows, while the table stays messy. Can this cause any sort of problems and how can I get the rows ordered permanently?

Initial rows:

```
SELECT * FROM ...

id   x1  x2  x3
_______________
0   'a' 'a' 'a'
1   'b' 'b' 'b'
2   'c' 'c' 'c'
3   'd' 'd' 'd'
4   'e' 'e' 'e'
5   'f' 'f' 'f'
6   'g' 'g' 'g'
```

Delete 3 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM ...

 0   'a' 'a' 'a'
1   'b' 'b' 'b'
2   'c' 'c' 'c'
6   'g' 'g' 'g'
```

Add 4 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM ...

0   'a' 'a' 'a'   <--- stays the same
1   'b' 'b' 'b'   <--- stays the same
2   'c' 'c' 'c'   <--- stays the same
7   'g' 'g' 'g'   <--- was 6
3   'i' 'i' 'i'   <--- new
4   'j' 'j' 'j'   <--- new
5   'k' 'k' 'k'   <--- new
6   'l' 'l' 'l'   <--- new
```

And finally:

```
SELECT * FROM ... sort by id ASC

0   'a' 'a' 'a'   <--- stays the same
1   'b' 'b' 'b'   <--- stays the same
2   'c' 'c' 'c'   <--- stays the same
3   'i' 'i' 'i'   <--- new
4   'j' 'j' 'j'   <--- new
5   'k' 'k' 'k'   <--- new
6   'l' 'l' 'l'   <--- new
7   'g' 'g' 'g'   <--- was 6
```

Comment: You need to reorder the table... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649180/reorder-rows-in-a-mysql-table

Comment: You can try to create `createDate` a column for this table and order by it.

Comment: Rows in a relational database have no intrinsic order. The same is true for the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is not a mess. A table is not an excel sheet, it's an unordered set of elements. When you want your data ordered in any way add a column that stores information how to order, like a timestamp column or a sequentially incrementing number. But don't use an auto_increment column. Those are just for identifying a row uniquely.